# Reload JPanel every X seconds (with threads?)

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a settings tab in my program. The data you can set there, is not only changeable from this panel. That's why I want to reload this data like every 5 seconds. I think this has to be done with an extra Thread, but my knowledge about Threads is minimal. I already have a reload method for this purpose.

What should I use to do this (and how...)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
 private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
 scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(yourRunnable, 5, 5, SECONDS);
```

Then reload your `JPanel` in `yourRunnable` (just follow the example from the JavaDocs).

Answer (score 5):

> but my knowledge about Threads is minimal...

1. You absolutely need to learn about threads in general, and the [Java Concurrency Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) can help.
2. Then you should learn about [concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) in particular.
3. Draw your GUI's graphic representation of the data in your JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method, or perhaps better, in a BufferedImage that is then displayed inside of `paintComponent(...)`.
4. Reload the data in a background thread such as a SwingWorker. This Worker can have a java.util.Timer or a `ScheduledExecutorService` as per syb0rg's answer (1+ to syb0rg's answer) that requests and obtains new data every 5 seconds.
5. Then call `repaint()` from the Swing event thread after your data is changed. If using a SwingWorker, the process/publish method pair could help with this. You could publish your data to the Swing event thread with this.

Comment: You spelled my name wrong :P +1 for all the useful stuff I didn't mention.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Timer` to update periodically your data.